# Cold start Squeak noise

Tags: engine, toyota, timing-belt, winter

I have an 04 Toyota Camry Solara. The car is in very good condition at 165k miles. Although since two winters ago I have noticed only in the cold mornings when I first start the car there is like a squeak/scrape noise. its not constant its only when I first start the car. This goes away during the day when the car is a little warmed up or in hot weather conditions. However now In April, the weather is a bit warm and I just noticed it again?? Anyone know what it is. I changed the belt at 100k and only started noticing this at around 120k

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a belt to me. Check the tension on the belt you replaced and see if the pulley needs an adjustment. I imagine there's a slight variation in how well the rubber "sticks" to the pulleys when it's cold vs when it's hot, so it slips more when it's cold. Check all the other belts too. You could also start the car and go listen around the engine and try and locate where the noise is coming from, that should give you an idea of what to check.